# Upgrade Mapstruct to 1.4.2.Final

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapstruct

I'm upgrading project **mapstruct** dependency from **1.2.0.Final** to **1.4.2.Final**.
Everything was going right util falling on a complex mapper which looks like the below snippet code:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public abstract class CustomMapper{

@Named("mapTestla")
@Mapping(target = "f", source = "t.f") 
public abstract TestlaDTO mapTestla(Testla t) {}

@Named("mapBar")
@Mapping(target = "t", source = "b.t", qualifiedByName = "mapTestla") 
public abstract BarDTO mapBar(Bar b) {}

@Mappings({@Mapping(target = "a", source = "f.a"), 
@Mapping(target = "b", source = "f.b", qualifiedByName = "mapBar")})
public abstract FooDTO mapFoo(Foo f) {}

}


class Foo {
 String a;
 Bar b;
}

class Bar {
 Tesla t;
}

class Testla {
String f;
}


class FooDTO {
 String a;
 Bar b;
}

class BarDTO {
 TeslaDTO t;
}

class TestlaDTO {
String f;
}
```

As You see in the error, mapstruct didn't detect the referenced method despite they are annotated with `@Named`. It looks like a **spring aop proxy** problem..

Any idea of this issue?

**PS:** I don't want to split the mapper into multiple mappers as we're running behind schedule and it may lead to impact.

**Error got:**

*Error : Qualifier error. No method found annotated with @Named#value: [ mapBar]. See https://mapstruct.org/faq/#qualifier for more info.*

*Error : Qualifier error. No method found annotated with @Named#value: [ mapTestla]. See https://mapstruct.org/faq/#qualifier for more info.*

Comment: I'm wondering why you need to explicitly state the methods using `qualifiedByName = "mapBar"`. MapStruct **should** detect them automatically if defined. So it should be enough to just declare / implement the methods for the types without any target annotation

Comment: make sure you have the correct `@Named` import. You'll want the `org.mapstruct.Named` one here not for example `javax.inject.Named`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have imported an incorrect `@Named` annotation from a different than MapStruct library.

Your example is working well with MapStruct  1.4.2.Final.

```java
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.Mapping;
import org.mapstruct.Mappings;
import org.mapstruct.Named;


@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public abstract class CustomMapper{

    @Named("mapTestla")
    @Mapping(target = "f", source = "t.f")
    public abstract TestlaDTO mapTestla(Testla t);

    @Named("mapBar")
    @Mapping(target = "t", source = "b.t", qualifiedByName = "mapTestla")
    public abstract BarDTO mapBar(Bar b);

    @Mappings({@Mapping(target = "a", source = "f.a"),
           @Mapping(target = "b", source = "f.b", qualifiedByName = "mapBar")})
    public abstract FooDTO mapFoo(Foo f) ;
}
```

Generated code:

```java
@Component
public class CustomMapperImpl extends CustomMapper {
    @Override
    public TestlaDTO mapTestla(Testla t) {
        if ( t == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        TestlaDTO testlaDTO = new TestlaDTO();
        testlaDTO.f = t.f;
        return testlaDTO;
    }

    @Override
    public BarDTO mapBar(Bar b) {
        if ( b == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        BarDTO barDTO = new BarDTO();
        barDTO.t = mapTestla( b.t );
        return barDTO;
    }

    @Override
    public FooDTO mapFoo(Foo f) {
        if ( f == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        FooDTO fooDTO = new FooDTO();
        fooDTO.a = f.a;
        fooDTO.b = mapBar( f.b );
        return fooDTO;
    }
}
```

According to documentation: [Mapping object references](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#mapping-object-references).

You do not need to specify inner objects mappings explicitly via method qualifier. It is enough to specify mapping methods for all objects that's all. MapStract will automatically qualify them.

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public abstract class CustomMapper {
    public abstract TestlaDTO mapTestla(Testla t);

    public abstract BarDTO mapBar(Bar b);

    public abstract FooDTO mapFoo(Foo f) ;
}
```

Generated code:

```java
@Component
public class CustomMapperImpl extends CustomMapper {

    @Override
    public TestlaDTO mapTestla(Testla t) {
        if ( t == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        TestlaDTO testlaDTO = new TestlaDTO();
        testlaDTO.f = t.f;
        return testlaDTO;
    }

    @Override
    public BarDTO mapBar(Bar b) {
        if ( b == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        BarDTO barDTO = new BarDTO();
        barDTO.t = mapTestla( b.t );
        return barDTO;
    }

    @Override
    public FooDTO mapFoo(Foo f) {
        if ( f == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        FooDTO fooDTO = new FooDTO();
        fooDTO.a = f.a;
        fooDTO.b = mapBar( f.b );
        return fooDTO;
    }
}
```

As you can see  MapStruct generated the same mapper code without additional annotations!

Comment: Removing @Named solved the issue. Thanks. Have Great day ! :)